# Add Menu to Activity's supportToolBar from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-menu

I have an `Activity` with a `Toolbar` that I set as the `supportActionBar`. From this `Activity` I have various `Fragments` each with a customized `ActionBar`. I am able to call `menu.clear()` to remove the existing `Menu` but I am  however unable to add another `Menu` in the same `Fragment`. This seems strange because `menu.clear()` behaves just as I would expect, but when calling `inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_custom_menu,menu);` appears to do nothing.

Example Fragment where I wish to modify the `supportActionBar`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    mGroupViewModel = 
    ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(GroupsViewModel.class);
}
...
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //Inflating seems to do nothing.
    Log.i(TAG,"IN THE ONCREATEOPTIONSMENU FOR FRAGMENT.");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.group_edit_toolbar,menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.i(TAG,"ONPREPARE OPTIONS MENU IN FRAGMENT.");
    menu.clear();
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Clearly there is something I don't understand but I can't narrow down on what that problem is.

Would a better approach be to have each `Fragment` have their own `Toolbar` instead of all my fragments modifying the hosting activity's `supportActionBar`?

**UPDATE**
After further testing, I notice that if I try to assign a local `MenuItem` in my `Fragment`, I receive a null pointer exception unless I first inflate a menu in the `Fragment` itself. This is leading me to think that I am not hijacking control of the `Activity`'s `supportActionBar` in the `Fragment`, but rather am trying to create a separate `ActionBar` for the `Fragment`. Would anyone be able to supplement my thinking here?

`Fragment`'s menu callbacks:

```
MenuItem editItem;
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.i(TAG,"IN ONCREATEOPTIONS");
    menu.clear();
    //MUST INFLATE MENU OTHERWISE WE GET NULL ERROR.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_actionbar,menu);
    editItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit_group);
    Log.i(TAG,"edititem: "+editItem.getItemId());
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

// This is called every time the Menu opens.
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.i(TAG,"IN THE on prepare FOR FRAGMENT.");
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_create_group).setVisible(false);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_create_group).setEnabled(false);
    if(owner.equals(currUser)){
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit_group).setEnabled(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit_group).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit_group).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit_group).setEnabled(false);
    }
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onPrepareOptionsMenu` is always called after `onCreateOptionsMenu` and there you're deleting your recently inflated menu! 
Just delete `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi Ayesh. The same problem is still occurring even after commenting out the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` callback. It seems that I am also only able to correctly execute `menu.clear()` inside of `onPrepareOptionsMenu` as well. I would expect if I could clear a `menu` here, then I would also be able to add one as well. Any thoughts?